# MSMQ:How to find out the original message by the acknowledgment message?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I  am  sending messages by specify acknowledgment queue  so that i can figure out whether the message has reach the target queue.
The code is below:

```
 string queuePath = @"FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:127.0.0.1\PRIVATE$\testqueue";
                    string ackPath = @".\private$\ack";
                    MessageQueue msmq = new MessageQueue(queuePath,QueueAccessMode.SendAndReceive);
                    tran.Begin();
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.UseAuthentication = false;
                    msg.Recoverable = true;
                    msg.Body = "HelloWorld";
                    msg.AcknowledgeType = AcknowledgeTypes.FullReachQueue;
                    msg.AdministrationQueue = new MessageQueue(ackPath, QueueAccessMode.ReceiveAndAdmin);
                    msmq.Send(msg, tran);
                    tran.Commit();
```

Every thing goes fine ,i can find the acknowledgment message in the queue "ack" after send out the message.
But i can`t figure out the relationship between acknowledgment message and original message.

So my question is :How to map the acknowledgment message to the original message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `System.Messaging.Message.CorrelationId` property.

> Gets or sets the message identifier used by acknowledgment, report,
>   and response messages to reference the original message.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.correlationid(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var msgToSend = new Message();
// ... set message props including admin queue
var targetQueue = new MessageQueue(...);
targetQueue.Send(msgToSend);

// Read acknowledgment
var adminQueue = new MessageQueue(ackPath);
var msgAck = adminQueue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(msgToSend.Id, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
if (msgAck)
{
    return msgAck.Acknowledgment;
}
```

There is `PeekByCorrelationId` method too, or overload forms of `ReceiveByCorrelationId` which you should check for more information.